# Should we have a "high effort" week to increase our question rate?

Tags: discussion

I, like most people here, really want to see this SE site be a success.  As pointed out previously, we are a little low on the question count.

I would like to suggest/propose a period of concerted activity in asking, answering and voting on questions amongst current members, so that we can improve the "good content" aspect of this site.

What I don't want this period to do is inflate the content with useless information.  The questions and answers need to be of high quality.  That is, we shouldn't just ask for asking's sake - but, I think it is perfectly acceptable to ask questions that possibly *could* be answered elsewhere but are answered here so as to both increase the amount of content and demonstrate the knowledge and helpfulness of the members.

For example, my key knowledge lies with football (soccer).  I can commit to providing answers to any question asked on this subject.  If we have similar members with other areas of knowledge we can soon build up our quality content.

I welcome your replies to this suggestion.

Comment: Movies & TV just launched their [Topic of the Week idea](http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/questions/479/topic-of-the-week) and is something we could explore, it sounds quite similar to your suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the absence of responses, I am posting this answer to state what **I** have done as part of my "high-effort" week and what you can do too.

**Vote**

I reviewed just about every question on the site.  There are currently less than 300 so it doesn't take long.  I upvoted the good questions, answers and comments and, if neccessary, downvoted those not up to scratch.  This shows our visitors good examples of questions and answers and it awards the rep to the people who deserve it.  This also helps us with our "avid users" stat on [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/27135/sports).

**Add a better answer**

In **my opinion**, the answers to [this question](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/840/ball-touching-the-ground-during-a-catch-in-cricket) did not have enough substance.  I researched the topic and posted what I deem to be a "better" answer.

**Add a <strike>better</strike> answer**

It's not a compeition to get the highest scoring answer.  In [this case](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/163/what-factors-give-a-home-advantage-and-how-big-is-it), there were some excellent answers already.  I simply added an answer that provided additional research, facts and links.  It's not going to become the new accepted answer but it improves the overall quality of the page for future visitors

**Make an existing answer better through editing**

Whilst there was absolutely nothing wrong with it, I edited [this answer](https://sports.stackexchange.com/a/533/496), simply to add a hyperlink to the corresponding rule.  A very simple edit but one that adds to the overall quality.

**Answer unanswered questions**

This is a Q&A site.  Have a look at the [unanswered questions](https://sports.stackexchange.com/unanswered).  Can you answer any of them?  Go for it.

**Ask questions**

I asked some questions.  Simple enough; it doesn't need any more explanation.

**Offer a bounty**

Encourage others to contribute to a question which interests you by offering a bounty for a great answer.  It's amazing what people will do for a little extra rep!

**Dedicate some time to creating an Epic Answer™**

Pick a question that interests you and challenge yourself to create the ultimate answer.  [This formula 1 question](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/696/in-the-history-of-formula-1-when-has-the-pole-sitter-not-started-the-race-on-po) hadn't been answered and I wanted to know the answer too.  So, I set some time aside to research and create the best answer I possibly could.

**Promote the site**

It's quite simple.  "Know someone who can answer?" - send them a link.  I've also posted a couple of links on forums and reddit asking for experts to help answer for us.  Hopefully some of these will sign up and join the community.

Comment: Excellent answer. I am useless at thinking of questions (even on movies & tv where I am a pro-tem moderator) but I can follow some of your suggestions here. I can help with answering Rugby, Cricket, American Football and Skiing questions.

Comment: 1.5 years later, I have offered several bounties on others' questions, but there have been cases where there still were no answers to questions when the bounty expired. That, I surmise, comes down to subject-matter expertise.