# How did we do for the Olympics?

Tags: discussion, quality-evaluation

In response to this question: [What can we do to promote the site for the Olympics?](https://sports.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/169/what-can-we-do-to-promote-the-site-for-the-olympics)

As a community, how did we do for the Olympics? Where did we succeed? Where do we need to improve on moving forward?

Tags: [Olympics](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/olympics), [London 2012](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/london-2012)

Comment: For anyone interested in the site's traffic: http://www.quantcast.com/sports.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We *did* see a spike in views and visitors during the Olympic season (down there to the right):

[image]

That is very promising for the prospect of future promotions. The trick now is to boost your retention rate by keeping the quality high and doing a bit of patient hand-holding and education with your first-time users.

[**The Role of niceness in a Q&A**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/08/stack-exchange-is-not-a-forum-the-role-of-niceness-on-a-qa-site/)

Comment: For anyone curious: the first spike is a question that was on Reddit, and the two in June coincide with the Euro tournament.

Comment: Awesome graph!!